# Elevator Program using timer

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this problem that when the program reached the last floor, the timer won't increment. Any tips on how can I improve my code?

I tried using an If statement to decrement when it reached the top floor but the timer just stops

```
String inputFlr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What floor? (Maximum Floor :        5)");
int floorInt = Integer.parseInt(flr3);

timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        flr++;

        if (flr == 6) {
            flr--;
        }

        jLabel1.setText(""+ flr); 

        if(floorInt == flr) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have reached your destination");
            timer.stop();
            jLabel3.setText("Please choose your next destination");
        } 
    }
});
```

The floors should decrement(5,4,3,2,1) when it reached the top floor

Comment: it will only decrement at 6, not at 5. so 1->2->3->4->5->flr++; flr--;=5->flr++;flr--;=5;->flr++;flr--;=5 ...   you might want to save the direction of the elevator.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the only time the program is performing a decrement is in your 'if' statement,

```
if (flr == 6){
         flr--;
       }
```

If your goal is to make the program decrement for other floors, you will have to check for that as well.

Best of luck.